# Possible to work with commandline in php on webhost?

Tags: php, linux

i want to use this script  http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/
inside my codeigniter project.

I've only a shared webhosting package.

So i ask myself if it's possible to work with my codeigniter/php also on commandline?

I'm not conform with working on commandline, so please sorry for my question and thanks for explain me what is possible and what not.

Comment: Are you asking us if you can use the command line on your hosting? How would we know that? Have you asked them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is specific to a web host, and can be best answered by contacting their support staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has function allow to execute command on unix using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function and  [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) for powershell command.

**Command**

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
```

**Powershell** command

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Example:

```
// Chmod doesn't work it needs root permission.
// exec('chmod a+x /path/to/webkit2png');

// Make sur that webkit2png is installed
echo exec('webkit2png --help');
echo exec('webkit2png http://www.google.com/');
```